# Resize video inside src value?

Tags: php, wordpress, video

What script can change value of video size inside src

```
SRC="http://website.com/embed-bz874sdg1280ghsse750hse-828x178.html
```

828x178 is problem when someone opening site from mobile or tablet etc.

I would like to have script that will automatically resize this to 100% or some my predefined width like 620x430 for tablet or 480 x 250 for mobile and similar?

I don't have such knowledge to do this, I know to change css by media, and I did made my theme responsive, and I stuck on this thing.

I want to implement that script to WordPress short code, but I did not find any that actually can do this.

Update:

Maybe some script can rempove everything after last - character so it would stay http://website.com/embed-bz874sdg1280ghsse750hse, and than script would just add .html, and it would be http://website.com/embed-bz874sdg1280ghsse750hse.html.

Almost all such videos embeds have - before and full stop after size -828x178.

Comment: What code prints this video tag? Is it your theme, a plugin, other thing?

Comment: It is shortcode that takes src value and puts it into iframe. So atually at one point of my script I have value of src with height and width at end. for example $src = http://website.com/embed-bz874sdg1280ghsse750hse-828x178.html. it would be good if i can remove this 828x178 also, but still i dont see how, when sometimes it has 7 characters but if 100x70 or 1024x720 it has 6 or 8 character, so I cant remove characters in string after first full stop by number. I noticed all of this has - before and full stop after size, maybe some script can remove it with this helpers -828x178.